# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 for SoundCloud HTTP API

Tags: ios, afnetworking, soundcloud

I have an iPhone app that uses SoundCloud and it has been working totally fine until today it completely stopped working. This is the error I am getting from the [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:] method when I try to get a SoundCloud token from the server.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token/, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fde9a48bbc0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey=<CFURLResponse 0x7fde9a5941e0 [0x10a0d4a40]>{url = https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token/}}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token/}
```

Does anyone know why I would be seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

1012 is an authentication error. Check your API key to see if it was expired by SoundCloud.